# TFS Build hangs while pushing to remote rep

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, tfs, build

I wrote powershell script, which I am executing before the testrunner in a (tfs 2013 build). The build hangs when the script calls git push on a remote repository using ssh. If I run the same script from powershell on the build agent using the same user it works totally fine. If it gets triggered via the buildcontroller it just hangs.

I do have a testsystem within my LAN where it also works fine. The staging server is hosted outside of this environment. But as I said before: It works when I execute the script as the same user from the build agent's powershell directly.

this is what I'm doing

```
Set-Location $Env:TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY

$gitArgs = @(
'remote -v add {0} ssh://{1}@{2}{3}' -f $DeploymentEnvironment, $DeploymentUser, $ServerHost, $ServerRepoPath; , 
'push -v --progress {0} master ' -f $DeploymentEnvironment; )

Write-Verbose "Executing git commands"

$gitArgs | ForEach {
    Write-Host $_
    $proc = Start-Process -FilePath $GitExe -ArgumentList $_ -Wait -NoNewWindow;
    
    if($proc.ExitCode -ne 0){
        Write-Error "Git is having errors..."
        exit $proc.ExitCode
    }
}
```

This is the build log output I get:

> remote -v add staging ssh://user@MYSERVERIP/path/to/my/repo.git
>
> push -v --progress staging master
>
> Pushing to ssh://user@MYSERVERIP/path/to/my/repo.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research I finally found the solution.

There're actually two .ssh directories on the build agent.
If you're using the powershell directly it's using the one from the user directory.
During build it's using the .ssh directory from C:\Program Files\Git.ssh\

add the hosts to you **known_host file** and copy them to both (!) directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, when I was switching from http to ssh.

I was running the following command to accomplish it:

```
remote set-url origin $sshRemoteUrl
```

I even checked that everything was correct with:

```
git remote get-url origin
```

Only after testing in powershell on the build server, searching of SSH entries and what not, I found out that the set-url command only changes the fetch reference, no the push reference. For that `--push` is needed:

```
remote set-url origin $sshRemoteUrl --push
```